# mysql query select distinct value from two table with the count of sum value in two table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in db

1- i want to select distinct value from 2 tables

2- i want to print the number of each value

**Ex: if i have on t1**

```
t1
--------------
a

a

a

b
```

**t2:**

```
t2
--------------
a

b

c
```

the result will be:

```
a (4)

b (2)

c (1)
```

i try this but it not what i want

```
$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"select db_shopname from tbl_order UNION
SELECT db_shopname FROM tbl_item order by db_shopname asc")
or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$count=mysqli_num_rows($sql);
while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo $res['db_shopname'];echo $count ;echo"<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`. That way you merge the values from 2 tables into 1 virtual table. Then you can count the number of individual values using `GROUP BY` clause. Example:

```
select f, COUNT(f) as countf FROM
(select t1.f from t1 union all select t2.f from t2) t
GROUP BY f
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2502/2)

In PHP you can then use `$res['countf']` to print the count

Comment: $sql=mysqli_query($conn,"select db_shopname, COUNT(db_shopname) FROM
(select tbl_order.db_shopname from tbl_order union all select tbl_item.db_shopname from tbl_item) t
GROUP BY db_shopname")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$count=mysqli_num_rows($sql);
while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
 echo $res['db_shopname'];echo"<br/>";
 }  how to print the number ?

Comment: @jad instead `COUNT(db_shopname)` use `COUNT(db_shopname) as countshops` and then in PHP use `echo $res['countshops']`

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

select a.t1,count(a.t1) as cnt from(select t1 from t1  UNION all
select t2 as t1 from t2 )a group by a.t1